# How to get only the date excluding time in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

How to get only the date excluding time in asp.net c#. I want only the date to be given as input to search like eg 3/11/2013

Answer (score 9):

You can use [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to get only date part of DateTime object

```
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
```

A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to *12:00:00* midnight (*00:00:00*).

If you have the Date in string and want to convert it to DateTime object first then you can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
result = DateTime.ParseExact("3/11/2013", "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = your_Dt.Date;
```

OR

You can format it into whatever format you want as below:

```
dt.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

OR

You can convert the valued to shortdate as:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(your_Dt).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use this:

```
  @{
     DateTime dd=DateTiem.Now;
     string date=dd.toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
   }
```

Now to view just:

```
  @date
```

Answer (score 1):

I saved the database as datetime in MS-SQL 2014, but when i need to only in date i do as below .... in cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model.dbModelLst)
{
            <tr>
              <td>@item.ChargeFrequency</td>
              <td>@item.Charge</td>
              <td>@item.FromDate.ToShortDateString().ToString()</td>
              <td>@item.ToDate.ToShortDateString().ToString()</td>
              <td>@item.Inv_SerialNo.SerialNo</td>
              <td>@item.IncludeLic</td>
              <td>@item.Status</td>
               .....
               .....
           </tr>
}
```

Where dbModelist contain List of Model (IEnumerable)... I Solve this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are brining it back from the Database though MVC then use `ToShortDateString()`.

Example for a company registration date:
 `txtComRegDate.Text = Convert.ToString(blCompanyMaster.ComRegDate.ToShortDateString());`

Here `ComRegDate` where the data comes form Business Layer.